# How to request permission access from user without asking the user to insert information Google Sign-Up

Tags: perl, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-signin, google-authentication

I have implemented google sign-in for my web app, in which I've used this library: https://metacpan.org/pod/Google::RestApi::Auth::OAuth2Client to get the code value, the access token and after that the user's information (email, name, google-id).

My problem in this implementation is that the user is prompt for consent where he needs to insert his information (email and password) and I would like to redirect the user for consent where he is able to select the accounts, and not insert his information. I don't know if my implementation, where I make the GET request, is incorrect or if it is because of the library that I use.

In front-end, I have a form which calls a route that redirects to my back-end function 'on_google_login':

```
sub on_google_login {
  my $self = shift;
  my $redirect_name = $self->get_redirect_name();
  $self->session(redirect => $redirect_name);
  my $google = Google::RestApi::Auth::OAuth2Client->new(
    client_id     => $ENV{GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID},
    client_secret => $ENV{GOOGLE_SECRET},
    redirect_uri  => $ENV{GOOGLE_BASE_URL} . '/google_callback'
  );

  my $url = $google->authorize_url(
    display => 'page'
  );

  $self->redirect_to($url);
}
```

And this is my callback function, where I extract the 'code' and I request the user's information using the access token.

```
sub on_google_callback {
  my $self = shift;

  my $code = $self->req->param('code');
  my $google = Google::RestApi::Auth::OAuth2Client->new(
    client_id     => $ENV{GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID},
    client_secret => $ENV{GOOGLE_SECRET},
    redirect_uri  => $ENV{GOOGLE_BASE_URL} . '/google_callback'
  );

  if (not (defined $code)) {
    return $self->render(text => 'Did not connect to Google');
  }

  my $redirect_name = $self->session('redirect') // 'home';
  delete $self->session->{'redirect'};  
  my $access_token = $google->access_token($code)->access_token;
  my $url = $ENV{GOOGLE_ENDPOINT} . $access_token;
  my $request = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url);
  my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
  my $info = decode_json($ua->request($request)->content);
  my ($google_id, $name, $mail) = ($info->{sub}, $info->{name}, $info->{email});

  if (!defined $google_id) {
    return $self->render(
    template => 'validation/custom_error',
    title => 'Error logging in with Google',
    message => 'Sorry, something went wrong when attempting to log you in ' .
      'with Google. Please try again and contact us in the chat if this ' .
      'persists.',
    status => 400);
  }
  my $found_user = $self->db->resultset('User')->by_mail($mail);

  if ($found_user) {
    return unless validate_user_can_login($self, $found_user);
    return unless set_user_data_on_login($self, $found_user);
    $self->redirect_to($redirect_name);
  } else {
    $self->session(name => $name);
    $self->session(mail => $mail);
    $self->redirect_to('/register');
  }

  return;
}
```

Comment: Well if the user isnt logged into a google account they are going to be promoted to enter a lotin and password first.  You could add something called login hint which will force it to a single login.   I dont think there is anyway to force it to list accounts that are on the users machine thats normally an automatic thing done by the current browser, mine for example pops up and always asks me to pick my work or private account.